# what is the cause of this discrepancy between localhost and build app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-select

i am working on a react app, and have noticed a strange behavior.
when i try to use a filter, it causes an error:

```
react-dom.production.min.js:106 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at _ (iterableToArray.js:2:40)
    at x (toConsumableArray.js:6:36)
    at setFilters (gallerySlice.js:92:8)
    at createReducer.ts:294:20
    at produce (immerClass.ts:94:14)
    at createReducer.ts:293:18
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at c (createReducer.ts:260:25)
    at reducer (createSlice.ts:372:14)
    at redux.js:560:29
```

The confusing thing is that it only happens in a built and deployed version!

The filtering setup consists of two react-select modules, reconciled through a rtk slice.
The slice is here:

```
        setFilters: (state, action) => {
            const { kategorije, tagovi } = action.payload;

            console.log('kategorije:', kategorije);
            console.log('tagovi:', tagovi);

            state.selectedFilters = {
                kategorije: Array.isArray(kategorije)
                    ? kategorije.filter(Boolean)
                    : [],
                tagovi: Array.isArray(tagovi) ? tagovi.filter(Boolean) : [],
            };
        },
...
// Filteri
export const selectFilteredPhotos = state => {
    const { kategorije, tagovi } = state.gallery.selectedFilters || {};
    const allPhotos = state.gallery.photos;

    if (!kategorije && !tagovi) {
        return allPhotos;
    }

    return allPhotos.filter(photo => {
        const kategorijaMatches =
            !kategorije ||
            kategorije.length === 0 ||
            kategorije.every(
                filter =>
                    photo.kategorija && photo.kategorija.includes(filter)
            );

        const tagoviIncluded =
            !tagovi ||
            tagovi.length === 0 ||
            tagovi.every(
                filter => photo.tagovi && photo.tagovi.includes(filter)
            );

        return kategorijaMatches && tagoviIncluded;
    });
};
```

The filtering components are:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { setFilters } from '../redux/rtk/gallerySlice';

function KategorijeSelekt() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const selectedFilters = useSelector(
        state => state.gallery.selectedFilters
    );
    const [filterSelected, setFilterSelected] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setFilterSelected(selectedFilters?.kategorije || []);
    }, [selectedFilters]);

    const handleKategorijeFilterChange = selectedFilters => {
        const selectedFilterValues = selectedFilters.map(
            filter => filter.label
        );
        dispatch(setFilters({ kategorije: selectedFilterValues }));
        setFilterSelected(selectedFilterValues);
    };

    const customKategorijeOptions = [
        { value: 'gospodarski_objekti', label: 'gospodarski objekti' },
        { value: 'vazni_objekti', label: 'važni objekti' },
        { value: 'vjerski_objekti', label: 'vjerski objekti' },
        { value: 'arhitektura', label: 'arhitektura' },
        { value: 'ekologija', label: 'ekologija' },
        { value: 'tradicijska_gradnja', label: 'tradicijska gradnja' },
        { value: 'spomenici', label: 'spomenici' },
        { value: 'prirodni_resursi', label: 'prirodni resursi' },
        { value: 'stanovnistvo', label: 'stanovništvo' },
        { value: 'poljoprivreda', label: 'poljoprivreda' },
        { value: 'stocarstvo', label: 'stočarstvo' },
        { value: 'infrastruktura', label: 'infrastruktura' },
    ];

    const cusTom = {
        control: styles => ({
            ...styles,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            border: 'none',
            borderTop: '1px solid black',
            borderRadius: '0',
            cursor: 'pointer',
        }),
        option: (styles, { data, isDisabled, isFocused, isSelected }) => {
            return { ...styles, color: 'black', cursor: 'pointer' };
        },
        placeholder: styles => ({
            ...styles,
            color: '#18aa00',
            marginTop: '-13px',
            marginLeft: '-8px',
            fontSize: '22px',
        }),
        dropdownIndicator: provided => ({ ...provided, display: 'none' }),
        indicatorSeparator: provided => ({
            ...provided,
            display: 'none',
        }),
        menu: styles => ({
            ...styles,
            zIndex: '9999',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            width: '46vw',
            height: 'auto',
        }),
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Select
                id='kategorije-select'
                styles={cusTom}
                placeholder='unesi/odaberi'
                isSearchable
                isMulti
                options={customKategorijeOptions}
                value={
                    selectedFilters?.kategorije
                        ? selectedFilters?.kategorije.map(option => ({
                                label: option,
                                value: option,
                          }))
                        : []
                }
                onChange={handleKategorijeFilterChange}
                getOptionValue={option => option.value}
                getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
            />{' '}
            <label
                htmlFor='kategorije-select'
                style={{
                    fontSize: '22px',
                    color: '#7e7e77',
                }}
            >
                kategorije
            </label>
        </div>
    );
}

export default KategorijeSelekt;
```

and the other one:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { setFilters } from '../redux/rtk/gallerySlice';

function TagoviSelekt({ tagoviOptions }) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const selectedFilters = useSelector(
        state => state.gallery.selectedFilters
    );
    const [filterSelected, setFilterSelected] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Initialize the state with selected filters when the component mounts
        const initialSelectedFilters = selectedFilters?.tagovi || [];
        setFilterSelected(
            initialSelectedFilters.map(option => ({
                label: option,
                value: option,
            }))
        );
    }, [selectedFilters]);

    const handleTagoviFilterChange = selectedFilters => {
        const selectedFilterValues = selectedFilters.map(
            filter => filter.value
        );
        dispatch(setFilters({ tagovi: selectedFilterValues }));
        // Update the local state when filters change
        setFilterSelected(
            selectedFilters.map(option => ({
                label: option.label,
                value: option.value,
            }))
        );
    };

    const cusTom = {
        control: styles => ({
            ...styles,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            border: 'none',
            borderTop: '1px solid black',
            borderRadius: '0',
            cursor: 'pointer',
        }),
        option: (styles, { data, isDisabled, isFocused, isSelected }) => {
            console.log('selekt', data, isDisabled, isFocused, isSelected);
            return { ...styles, color: 'black', cursor: 'pointer' };
        },
        placeholder: styles => ({
            ...styles,
            color: '#18aa00',
            marginTop: '-13px',
            marginLeft: '-8px',
            fontSize: '22px',
        }),
        dropdownIndicator: provided => ({ ...provided, display: 'none' }),
        indicatorSeparator: provided => ({
            ...provided,
            display: 'none',
        }),
        menu: styles => ({ ...styles, zIndex: '999', cursor: 'pointer' }),
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Select
                styles={cusTom}
                placeholder='unesi/odaberi'
                isSearchable
                isMulti
                options={tagoviOptions}
                value={
                    selectedFilters?.tagovi
                        ? selectedFilters?.tagovi.map(option => ({
                                label: option,
                                value: option,
                          }))
                        : []
                }
                onChange={handleTagoviFilterChange}
                getOptionValue={option => option.value}
                getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
            />
            <label
                htmlFor='keyword-select'
                style={{ color: '#7e7e77', fontSize: '22px' }}
            >
                ključne riječi
            </label>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TagoviSelekt;
```

The reproducible example is [here](https://github.com/ydrea/Rleaf).

Answer (score 0):

apparently the issue was caused by a hosting lag - react on cpanel isn't exactly real-time...